# Is there an opposite of gairaigo, covering both kango and wago?

Tags: loanwords, terminology

Is there a term that means that something isn't *gairaigo*, words recently derived from (predominantly European) foreign languages?

For example, I'd like to say that 踊り is a non-*gairaigo* word, which could be *kango* or *wago* (also known as *yamato kotoba*), as opposed to the *gairaigo* word ダンス.

Comment: Coincidentally, there's a question about this pair of words: [What is the difference between 踊り and ダンス](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25606/what-is-the-difference-between-%E8%B8%8A%E3%82%8A-and-%E3%83%80%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9)

Comment: What's wrong with "*kango* or *wago*"?

Comment: @Earthli[n like character] if that’s what’s used, put that as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a natural/obvious choice for "non-*gairaigo*" would be just literally 非外来語. Of course it covers both *kango* and *wago*, as these aren't *gairaigo*.

The term is being used, for example in [this draft paper title (PDF)](https://www.ninjal.ac.jp/event/specialists/project-meeting/files/JCLWorkshop_no4_papers/JCLWorkshop_No4_35.pdf)

> 現代日本語書き言葉における非外来語のカタカナ表記事情
>   Frequency of Katakana Representation for Japanese Non-loan Words as Observed in the BCCWJ Corpus

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing in what situation you would like to use the word, I will give a few suggestions. I think that the top three are all pretty serviceable.

日本の言葉　－OK

日本語 －OK

普通の日本語 - OK, not as good as the one's above

外来語じゃない言葉 －OK

固有語 －OK, but not so common

在来語 －pretty obscure, but if it's for a thesis it's OK

Check [this site](http://www.hantaigo.com) out.